# Qt Signal and Slot connection doesn't seem to work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4

I've checked this a heap of times and cannot find my error.

In my main class, I have:

```
connect(userControl, SIGNAL(DataToPlot(std::vector<double>)), this, SLOT(test(std::vector<double>)));
```

In the same class I have a test function and prototype:

```
public slots:
    void test(std::vector<double>);

void RelayduinoGuiThreading::test(std::vector<double> x)
{
    123;  // I put a breakpoint on this line to check when the slot is called.
}
```

Running in a seperate thread, I have the following:

```
signals:
    void DataToPlot(std::vector<double>);

somefunction
{
        // Stuff...

        std::vector<double> x;
        emit(DataToPlot(x));
}
```

Now here's the thing, if I change the std::vector to an int, or a double, it works.

Also, #include  is in both class headers.

I even have somewhere else in my project where I emit an std::vector and catch the signal and have no problems with that.

Help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is mentioned in Qt Docu

> Note that if you intend to use the type in queued signal and slot connections or in QObject's property system, you also have to call qRegisterMetaType() since the names are resolved at runtime.

So in your main application you have to call:

```
qRegisterMetaType<std::vector<float> >("std::vector<float>");
```

and in your `RelayduinoGuiThreading` header file (as tibur mentioned):

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<float>);
```

[Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) is the documentation in detail

Comment: Thank you. I will certainly look into the QMetaType Class. Though I am very curious as to why std::vector<int> worked somewhere else in my project, yet std::vector<double> doesn't. Why would std::vector<int> be 'registered' and not std::vector<double>? Anyway, thanks for the information. I really have no idea how I was supposed to find that... The problem seems as though it could've been anything.

Comment: After changing std::vector<float> to std::vector<double> it worked.  I'm not too sure why both of you put float instead of double, but doesn't matter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your `RelayduinoGuiThreading` header:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<float>);
```